# How to properly implement a loss function using tf-keras-vis?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to understand the following snippet of code demonstrated in [this example](https://github.com/keisen/tf-keras-vis/blob/master/examples/attentions.ipynb) of tf-keras-vis use.

I am trying to create saliency maps for a project I have been working on. The snippet I am having issues with is as follows:

**Define necessary functions**

**Define Loss functions**

You MUST define loss function that return target scores. Here, it returns the scores corresponding Goldfish, Bear, Assault Rifle.

```
# The 'output' variable refer to the output of the model,
# so, in this case, `output` shape is `(3, 1000)` i.e., (samples, classes).
def loss(output):
    # 1 is the imagenet index corresponding to Goldfish, 294 to Bear and 413 to Assault Rifle.
    return (output[0][1], output[1][294], output[2][413])
```

How is this exactly calculating loss? I need to understand this so I can modify it to apply it to my own model. If I simply type:

```
def loss(output):
    return output
```

Something resembling a saliency map is output but I need to understand what is going on with the original code piece

Answer (score 1):

From how I understand the code in the linked example, the "loss" function simply returns the network outputs that you're interested in analyzing.

In the sample code:

```
def loss(output):
    # 1 is the imagenet index corresponding to Goldfish, 294 to Bear and 413 to Assault Rifle.
    return (output[0][1], output[1][294], output[2][413])
```

the "loss" is set up to generate three saliency images, one per input image (notethat it could be more). For the first one, since the image is a goldfish image, you return the output matching the goldfish label (`output[0][1]`, where image 0 is the goldfish one and label 1 is goldfish) and similarly you return the outputs of class "Bear" and "Assault Rifle" for the other two sample images.

So, provided that you know what labels the sample images you're feeding have, just return the model's output for those labels.

Comment: Hello GPhilo, Thanks for your response. So in my case I am predicting whether an image is a 1 or a 0. It seems that in my case I could just iterate over instead of having 3 outputs since each image I am predicting whether it is a 1 or 0. So in the code all I need to output from the loss function is the model's output for each image? I am struggling to understand what this has to do with 'loss', or even the point of such a function

Comment: I don't know exactly how the methods implemented work, but if I understood them correctly, the visualization they produce is the "explantion" of what areas of the image the model uses to produce a certain output. The way they're computed is based on studying how the output changes altering the input pixels, so each image is specific to one output for each image. You can view all outputs, of course, I just don't know if the views will be meaningful.